# ModelState.AddModelError on form level with ASP.NET MVC 2 RC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, addmodelerror

In the previous versions on ASP.NET MVC, you could use `ModelState.AddModelError("**_FORM**", "error")` to make an error on the form-level instead of a property-level. This seems not to work anymore with the new RC of ASP.NET MVC 2.

Is there another way how to do it? I use `<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>` at my View-file...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally use `AddModelError(""` - I don't know where does _FORM come from? - and `ValidationSummary()` is no black magic - I use my own helper instead that, for example, includes specific (user-specific) exceptions messages into output. The helper is very easy to write - a simple foreach loop over ModelState - so you may consider writing your own one. There you're free to show form-level, property-level, or whatever you like.

Comment: I did try AddModelError(null, ... but that didn't work. AddModelError("", ... is working like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the error are inside modelstate and is send to the helper class of validationsummary by following argument:

```
this.ViewData.ModelState.Keys

this.ViewData.ModelState.Values
```